# How do I observe properties in an Ember route template?

Tags: ember.js, properties, routes

I have a route that sometimes shows a dialog.  My idea for this was to create a component like this:

```
{{modal-dialog visible=dialogVisible contents=dialogContents}}
```

The route would, as needed, set the dialogVisible and dialogContents properties, and the template would pass these properties on to the `modal-dialog` component accordingly, so the dialog would appear and show the correct content.

But that doesn't work.  Templates observe routes' models, not their properties.  How can I get access to route properties in my template?

Comment: There is great addon [ember-modal-dialog](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-modal-dialog). That could maybe help you in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is your problem. The way your're doing it seems correct.

*controllers/index.js*

```
actions: {
      createModal: function(someSpecialContent) {
          this.set('dialogVisible', true);
          this.set('dialogContents', someSpecialContent);
          $('#modalId').modal('show');
      }
  }
```

*templates/index.hbs*

```
{{modal-dialog visible=dialogVisible contents=dialogContents}}
```

*templates/components/modal-dialog.hbs*

```
{{#if visible}}

    your modal html here 
    ...
   <div class="modal-body">                        
     {{#each contents as |content|}}
          {{content.stuff}}
     {{/each}}
  </div>
    ...

{{/if}}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a future-proof approach: "Controllers are very much like components, so much so that in future versions of Ember, controllers will be replaced entirely with components." http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/controllers/

Comment: @ed94133 The logics still remain the same, instead of controllers there will be routable components with an argument of model. for instance routes/ my-dir/index.js and components/my-dir/index-js

Answer (score 0):

Have you simply tried `.observes('model.PROPERTY_NAME')`?

Why is it that you're trying to observe this property from the route? I've done something similar before and it seemed to make much more sense setting the dialogVisible property on the controller, not the route.